# How to use conditions with Reduce?

Tags: inequalities

I am solving a simple inequality with `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[r^2-d^2>0,d]
```

I get a correct solution, but I would like to impose the condition `r>0` in order to simplify the result, how can I do that?

Comment: `FullSimplify[Reduce[{r^2 - d^2 > 0, r > 0}, d], r > 0]` or `FullSimplify[Reduce[r^2 - d^2 > 0, d], r > 0]`?

Comment: `Reduce[r^2 - d^2 > 0 && r > 0, d] // FullSimplify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[r^2 - d^2 > 0, d], r > 0]
```

> ```
>  -r < d < r
> ```

Alternatively,

```
Reduce[{r^2 - d^2 > 0, r > 0}, d]
```

> ```
>  r > 0 && -Sqrt[r^2] < d < Sqrt[r^2]
> ```

```
FullSimplify[%, r > 0 ]
```

> ```
> -r < d < r
> ```

Comment: Of course. I am having a slow morning thanks!